# What am I doing wrong with this nested block

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, static-block

I am using `magento 1.9` and want to insert cookie restriction notice block on my page
[image]

then try to render it in my homepage.phtml
[image]

but got nothing
[image]

and this static block(cookie restriction notice block) is enabled

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using `getChildChildHtml('cookies.notice')`

Use  `getChildHtml('cookies.notice')`

We are using`getChildChildHtml` when we want to get 2nd level of child block

For getting first level of child block we are using `getChildHtml` method

Answer (score 6):

Try `getChildHtml` rather than `getChildChildHtml`.

Also use `block_id` rather than `id`:

```
<action method="setBlockId">
    <block_id>my_block</block_id>
</action>
```

Comment: I am 20sec Faster

Comment: Damn it! If only I didn't have an extra sip of coffee!

Comment: Ha Ha , That's why I didn't take coffee on my desk